# WebPack: replace 'require' result with {}

Tags: typescript, webpack, webpack-2

I have a base class in my TypeScript code which accepts an object as one of args. I have a lot of classes which extends this base class. This looks like:

```
class Finances extends I18nBase {
    constructor(){
        super(require('./finances.tran.json'));
    }
}
```

I've used this approach to create and debug i18n for my site. Now I need to get rid of json fragments in production code. But I want to switch them off, not to remove them entirely from code, as if I may need em later.

So I've tried WebPack IgnorePlugin, but it gives me `Cannot find module "./finances.tran.json"` error.

Is there any way to replace all `require` of `tran\.json` with `{}` at a building stage?

**UPDATE**

Solved it with dummy `.json` file like this:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(/tran\.json$/, 
        path.resolve(__dirname, srcRoot, 'empty_tran.json'))
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved it with dummy `.json` file like this:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(/tran\.json$/, 
        path.resolve(__dirname, srcRoot, 'empty_tran.json'))
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use something like [string-replace-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-replace-loader) to replace the strings.

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.ts$/,
      loader: 'string-replace',
      query: { 
        search: '.\.\/finances\.tran\.json', replace: '{}',
        flags: 'g' 
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Or some other regular expression instead of the one i've used here to cover a greater amount of json files.